# How to save sequences from the take recorder outside of the project folder in Unreal Engine 5 (5.3)?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal

Is there a way to save sequences captured with the take recorder to be saved in a directory outside of the project folder?

I need to generate hundreds of sequences with the take recorder but I need to save them in an external drive due to specific space constraints.

I tried to do an absolute path to the external drive in the take recorder settings, however, looks like it requires a path relative to the project folder and cannot be anything outside it by default

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Now that I think about it the solution was very simple. I just migrated the whole project folder onto the external drive so the take recorder sequences save there by default